# Missing two syntactical expressions of rules of inference in sentential logic

Tags: logic, philosophy-of-logic, reason, propositional-logic

I have a table of the rules of inference in propositional logic. Among the entries are an Associative and a Commutative. The Associative rule is expressed with disjunction, but the commutative is expressed with conjunction. Obviously, in terms of permutations of syntax, it seems there should be both an Associativity of Conjuction and Disjunction as two distinct expressions as well as Commutativity of Conjunction and Disjunction as two distinct expressions. And yet in the table, there is not.

Is it historical? Might it be a space constraint? Did the author have a preference? Is it understood that some rules of inferences are preferential as canonical primitives in computation? Is there a canonical taxonomy of sentential rules of inference? Is there some unknown unknown relevant to my question?

**What would be the rationale for excluding two of the four possible syntactical configurations in the resource I have listing the rules of inference?**

Comment: Possibly the author is keeping the number of rules to a minimum. If one or other of conjunction and disjunction is commutative and associative, the other is too by inference from de Morgan. It's hard to say without seeing the list or knowing what the author was trying to achieve.

Comment: @Bumble Well, as the list is an aged photocopy free of its author's text by reference, it sounds to be the case that the question, as constructed, is unanswerable and largely a question of hermeneutics more than one related to a rationale related to constructing and categorizing a grammar of logic stemming from canonical practice. I suppose if one accepts that Boolean logic motivates the metalanguage of sentential logic, there is no foundation to see expression in disjunction or conjunction priviledged. There just happens to be no and-or symbolic notation equivalent to the arithmetic '±'.

Comment: @JD the equivalent of and/or is just or, here, because xor is the not-and counterpart (besides nand itself, of course). So symbolically, the usual ∨ can be taken for ±, I think.

Comment: @KristianBerry LOL I'll have to think about the potential failure of my grammatical analogy. :D

Comment: Could you list what the rules the table had were in logical notation or add a screenshot of the table? Was the associative rule “a or (b or c) = (a or b) or c”, and the commutative “a and b = b and a”? Do you think the answer might be that it was completely accidental, the author just randomly used two examples?